# How to get the right elements with XDocument query

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am having trouble to get the query right when trying to parse a XML file using XDocument.

What I want:

***Give me all Values of "Name" Elements of Step with id = "id_3" So the result should be a list containing "Name of part 1, Name of part 2, Name of part 3, Name of part 4***.

**Input XML:**

```
<MyXML>
   <Step id="id_1" type="type1">
     <Name>Some Name</Name>
     <Location>1</Location>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Step>
   <Step id="id_2" type="type1">
     <Name>>Some Name</Name>
     <Location>2</Location>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Step>
   <Step id="id_3" type="type2">
     <Instruction>This is some text</Instruction>
     <Component>
       <Name>Name of part 1</Name> // --> I want this value
       <Transition_Start>-0.2,0.01,0.0</Transition_Start>
       <Transition_End>0,0.01,0.0</Transition_End>
     </Component>
     <Component>
       <Name>Name of part 2</Name> // --> and this
       <Transition_Start>0.2,0.01,0</Transition_Start>
       <Transition_End>0,0.01,0</Transition_End>
     </Component>
     <Component>
       <Name>Name of part 3</Name> // --> and this
       <Transition_Start>0.05,0.1004,0.0333</Transition_Start>
       <Transition_End>-0.0803,0.1004,0.0333</Transition_End>
     </Component>
     <Component>
       <Name>Name of part 4</Name> // --> and this
       <Transition_Start>-0.0107,0.0383,-0.2328</Transition_Start>
       <Transition_End>-0.0107,0.0383,-0.2328</Transition_End>
     </Component>
   </Step>
 </MyXML>
```

I tried something like this (in Unity3D).

```
IEnumerable<XElement> e_nameOfObjects = 
                from el in myXMLDoc.Root.Elements ("Step")
                where (string)el.Attribute ("id") == "id_" + currentStep
                select el.Elements ("Component");

foreach (XElement e in e_nameOfObjects) {
    Debug.Log (e.Element("Name"));
}
```

**The error message:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'
>    to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion
>    exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Please describe in what way it is not working? Are you getting the wrong data, an exception, something else? Please detail in the question.

Comment: "Please detail in the question" (code/errors in comments are too hard to read).

Comment: IEnumerable<XElement> e_nameOfObjects = 
           (from el in myXMLDoc.Root.Elements ("Step")
            where (string)el.Attribute ("id") == "id_" + currentStep
            select el.Elements ("Component")).ToList();

Comment: Thanks. But this still gives me the following error message: 
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>>' to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You have a dimension mismatch, the query returns a __List of List of XElement__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the Component by using the `Elements` method and then select `Name` inside those components like this:-

```
var names = myXMLDoc.Descendants("Step")
            .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "id_3")
            .Elements("Component")
            .Select(x => (string)x.Element("Name"));
```

Here, *names* will return `IEnumerable<string>` on which you can easily iterate through foreach loop.

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LocKFs)